# How do i render child route components under a parent route in react router without routing to the child paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<Route path="/dashboard" element={<DashboardLayout />}>
  <Route index element={<DashboardHome />} />
  <Route path="update-profile" element={<UpdateProfileForm />} />
  <Route path="bookmarks" element={<Bookmarks />} />
</Route>
```

I have my routes setup like this, but i want all the child routes of dashboard to render under the same path without actually routing to the child routes

Example: The index route is dashboard Home component and it renders in `/dashboard` path
I want `update-profile`, `bookmarks` to render under `/dashboard` path .Not like switching to `/dashboard/update-profile` path in the browser.

If i click bookmarks in my dashboard navbar it should render the `Bookmarks` component but my path should be `/dashboard` in the browser itself, for now it is routing to the `/dashboard/bookmarks`.

How to overcome this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is or what you are asking for. You are effectively rendering 3 routes, `"/dashboard"`, `"/dashboard/update-profile"`, and `"/dashboard/bookmarks"`. What are you expecting? Are you ***not*** wanting to use any routes for the `UpdateProfileForm` and `Bookmarks` components?

Comment: @DrewReese, sorry for not describing the question well,

I want my update-profile, bookmarks to render under `/dashboard` and my browser path should be `/dashboard` route but as of now `/dashboard/update-profile` is the browser's path

Comment: @MOHANSINGH not sure if it’s possible but you can conditional render in your dashboard component

Comment: So move `UpdateProfileForm` and `Bookmarks` components to be rendered by the `DashboardHome` component. Don't render the other components on other routes.

Answer (score 1):

As far as, I have understood you question, You just need to configure the parent component in routing. All the child components need not to be configured in the routing.

```
<Route path="/dashboard" element={<DashboardLayout />}>
  <Route index element={<DashboardHome />} />
</Route>
```

The child components can be imported inside the parent component and used inside the parent component itself like below,

DashboardHome.jsx

```
import 'Bookmarkscomponent' from Bookmarkscomponent.jsx
import 'Slidercomponent' from Slidercomponent.jsx

export default function DashboardHome() {
 return (
    <>
      <Slidercomponent />
      <Bookmarkscomponent />
    </>
 )
}
```

Also,  If you want to render the same `/dashboard` when you click the `Bookmark`. Then you can configure the same route in the `link` like below,

```
<Link to="/dashboard">Bookmark</Link>
```